# How to retrieve value of data in the mongo collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb

In mongodb, I have a collection Students with following struture

```
{
 "_id" : "123",
    "username" : "user@gmail.com",
}
```

I want to retrieve the value 'user@gmail.com' how do I do that?

Without explicitly finding for user@gmail.com using `db.getCollection('students').find({username:"hellouser@gmail.com"})`

Comment: what language are you using to query mongoDB?

Comment: Have you even tried?

Comment: Yes I have tried. I am using javascript. I tried even using robomongo console (mongoshell) to just retrieve the value but could not do it.                                         So I want to get user@gmail.com without using db.getCollection('students').find({username:"hellouser@gmail.com"})            As I want the list of all the such fields present in the collection

Comment: If you are using `JavaScript`, why have you tagged `Java`?

Answer (score 0):

According to the additional information you provided in your comment, you want to retrieve the usernames of all students in your collection. Here is the code for doing so:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';

mongo.connect(url, function(e, db) {
    if (e) return console.error(e);
    db.collection('students').find().project({_id: 0, username: 1}).forEach(function(doc) {
        console.log(doc.username);
    }, function(e){
        if(e)   console.error(e);
        db.close();
    });
});
```

Assuming you have two students in your collection the output could look like this:

```
user@gmail.com
user1@gmail.com
```

If you want to have the usernames in an array, use toArray instead of forEach (have a look at the MongoDB api docs for usage info: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Cursor.html#toArray)